# use a html table pagination on a certain table only

Tags: php, jquery

I have a pagination and it applies to all the tables.

What if i would like to apply it on a certain table coz i have a page with 2 tables the table under is the one I would like to have the pagination in the page im creating.

I have a jquery code like this

```
function draw()
{
 $('tr').hide();
}
```

If I have a table named subTable, how would I code it to hide?

My idea is something like `$('#subTable')` and somehow connect it to its  `$('tr')` and then hide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe like this ? :

`$('#subTable tr').hide();`

This will hide all `tr` elements from table which id is `subTable`

Comment: if you're going to hide all the rows, why not just hide the table?

Comment: @pete sorry sir, that's just a portion of my code, sorry I'm lazy